# How can I setinterval with Nodej.s for a specific time of day?

Tags: node.js, setinterval

I have the following function that runs every hour but I would like it to run once per day at 3 AM:

```
setInterval(async () => {
    await updateData();
}, 1000 * 60 * 30);
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Agree w/ the answer that recommends a library; it's just not worth the effort. That said, depending on the resolution you need, you could also check the current time every *n* minutes (or whatever) and if it's "near" the desired time, and hasn't already run during the time slot (e.g., has it run in the last 24h), run the task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setInterval` doesn't have this functionality directly. You could play around with date math to make this happen, but honestly, the easiest approach would probably be to use a thrid-party that does this for you, like [`node-cron`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron).

First, you'd need to install it:

```bash
npm install node-cron
```

Then, in your code:

```js
cron = require('node-cron'); 
cron.schedule('0 3 * * *', async () => {
    await updateData();
});
```

Comment: And of course if the code is running on a *NIX system they can just use the system's cron tool/systemd.

Comment: I am getting this error with your solution:

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

Comment: @adminadmin missed the `async` there, mea culpa. Edited and fixed.